# Split array based on value

Tags: python

I have an array:

```
foo = ['1', '2', '', '1', '2', '3', '', '1', '', '2']
```

¿Is there any efficient way to split this array into sub-arrays using '' as separator?

I want to get:

```
foo = [['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1'], ['2']]
```

Comment: Your `foo` looks like a regular list. Are you sure it's a numpy array?

Answer (score 4):

In one line:

```
[list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(foo, lambda x: x == '') if not k]
```

Edit:

From the oficial documentation:

groupby

> generates a break or new group every time the value of the key
> function changes (which is why it is usually necessary to have sorted
> the data using the same key function).

The key I generate can be `True`, or `False`. It changes each time we find the empty string element. So when it's True, g will contain an iterable with all the element before finding an empty string. So I convert this iterable as a list, and of course I add the group only when the key change

Don't know how to explain it better, sorry :/ Hope it helped

Comment: Could you explain it please?

Comment: @renton01 I tried

Comment: _"add the group only when the key change"_ you actually add the group only when the key is truthy, i.e. non-empty strings

Comment: You could also use `''.__eq__` instead of `lambda x: x == ''`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list containing a single list.

```
output = [[]]
```

Now, iterate over your input list. If the item is not `''`, append it to the last element of `output`. If it is, add an empty list to output.

```
for item in foo:
    if item == '':
        output.append([])
    else:
        output[-1].append(item)
```

At the end of this, you have your desired `output`

```
[['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1'], ['2']]
```